# Progress bar taking abnormally long with applied function

Tags: r, progress-bar, lapply

I have a function that I'd like to apply to a large numeric vector:

```
numbers <- 1:100000

prime <- function(n){
  if(sum(n/1:n==n%/%1:n)==2){TRUE}
  else{FALSE}
}

results <- lapply(numbers, prime)
```

This takes **~90 seconds** to complete:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(results <- lapply(numbers, prime), times = 1)
Unit: seconds
                                      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        results <- lapply(numbers, prime)  89.75836 89.75836 89.75836 89.75836 89.75836 89.75836     1
```

I'd like to add a progress bar to see how much time is left. But when I try to implement one from the `progress` package using `purrr::walk`, it says the estimated time of completion is **2 hours**! I got the syntax from the "`purrr` iterators" section of the package's [Github](https://github.com/r-lib/progress).

```
> pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(format = "computing [:bar] :percent time left: :eta", total = 100, show_after = 0)
> purrr::walk(1:100, ~{pb$tick();results <<- lapply(numbers, prime)})
computing [====>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------]   4% time left:  2h
```

I've figured out an alternate way to get what I want with using the `timer` option with `pbapply::pblapply`, but I'm wondering why the method from the `progress` package isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks `walk` is running the same code 100 times. I think for each step in that 100 it is producing `results2` again.

In the below `not_purrr` is how I think it could be done with 100 breakpoints setup before the loop

```
numbers <- 1:1000
microbenchmark('original'={
  results <- lapply(numbers, prime)
}, 
'not_purrr'={
  checkpoints <- ceiling(seq(min(numbers), max(numbers), length.out = 100))
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(format = "computing [:bar] :percent time left: :eta", total = 100, show_after = 0)
  foo <- lapply(numbers, function(x){
    if(x %in% checkpoints) pb$tick()
    prime(x)
  })
},
'purrr'={
    pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(format = "computing [:bar] :percent time left: :eta", total = 100, show_after = 0)
    purrr::walk(1:100, ~{pb$tick();results2 <<- lapply(numbers, prime)})
}, times=5)
```

You can kind of see this using `profvis` and adding some `sys.sleep` to see the gaps:

```
numbers <- 1:10000
profvis::profvis({
  pb <- progress::progress_bar$new(format = "computing [:bar] :percent time left: :eta", total = 10, show_after = 0)
  purrr::walk(1:10, ~{
    pb$tick();
    results2 <<- lapply(numbers, prime);
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  })
})
```